# SVG to PNG Full SVG image

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am using the library http://www.getorgchart.com/ to produce a large organisational chart diagram. This renders the chart in `<svg></svg>` tags.

My problem is, the built in "print" function doesn't print the entire chart, just the visible section. As my chart has around 180 people on it, it expands horizontally quite far!

What I need to be able to do, is capture all the SVG data and export it to PDF/PNG/JPG whichever of these (PDF would be ideal with the scalability intact). I've tried several libraries to try and complete this task, and failed thus far! I've tried using `canvg` and also other libraries that i've found such as https://github.com/exupero/saveSvgAsPng (which worked to an extent but all the line paths were messed up and it only printed the visible section of the svg not the entire chart).

**UPDATE** Solution must be either client-side or easily implemented on internal servers!

Using the last library I had:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#printme').click(function(){
            saveSvgAsPng(document.getElementById("svgChart"), "diagram.png");
        });
});
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Try using cloudformatter, see http://jsfiddle.net/zvx6eb7e/317/ and replace the SVG with yours. You may need to change page dimensions to be large enough for your SVG, If you have an issue, just save the fiddle and comment and I can look at it

Comment: By the name, does it require the element to be sent to an online server? If so that may not be suitable as it is an internal project. I was aiming to try and do it front-end or on our local servers.

Comment: How do you print it? You could import the svg into illustrator and print it from there. Converting to png will make it less ideal for printing, especially if it's large format.

Comment: I'd love to say we could do that but unfortunately limitations of the network is there are no options to install a vector based graphic processor or I would be good to go! My thoughts exactly with PNG, ideally i would go with PDF over several pages to keep the scalable element. PNG would be a last resort, though if it comes to it I will take it so long as the SVG is legible or can be printed large enough across several pages.